# What is wrong with my omnet installation?

Tags: installation, omnet++

Trying to install and use OmNet. I follow the InstallationGuide but after running the "make" command, during "Compiling sim" under clistener.cc I get this:

```
clistener.cc:56:5: warning: 'receiveSignal' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    receiveSignal(c, signalID, checked_int_cast<long>(i,nullptr,msg), d);
    ^
C:/OmNet/omnetpp-6.0.1/include/omnetpp/clistener.h:206:7: note: 'receiveSignal' has been explicitly marked deprecated
      here
    [[deprecated]] virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, long i, cObject *details);
      ^
clistener.cc:66:5: warning: 'receiveSignal' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    receiveSignal(c, signalID, checked_int_cast<unsigned long>(i,nullptr,msg), d);
    ^
C:/OmNet/omnetpp-6.0.1/include/omnetpp/clistener.h:207:7: note: 'receiveSignal' has been explicitly marked deprecated
      here
    [[deprecated]] virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, unsigned long i, cObjec...
      ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Then in the end during "Compiling qtenv" i get this:

```
===== Compiling qtenv ====
/opt/mingw64/bin/uic: /opt/mingw64/bin/uic: klarte ikke å kjøre binærfil 
make[2]: *** [Makefile:99: ui_animationcontrollerdialog.h] Error 126
make[1]: *** [Makefile:134: qtenv] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:35: allmodes] Error 2
```

First line in norwegian, means "could not run binaryfile"

The next thing the installation guide asks me to do is to verify the installation  by starting the aloha example.

After ./aloha I get this:
bash: ./aloha: No such file or directory

So, where do I go from here?

Further, OmNet wills start, but i get errors when trying to build projects.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the version and, if possible, the link to  the installationGuide that you used, or (even better) to include the actual statement that you used when installing.

Comment: Version: 6.0.1
Link to installation guide: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf
Your final question, I don't quite understand...

Comment: Make sure that your real time antivirus protection is turned off.